# HTML5 video fallback when all types unsupported

Tags: html, html5-video

In the HTML5 spec, it suggests you put fallback material in the `<video>` tag for older browsers that do not support it.

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

However, I cannot find anything for fallbacks when all source types are unsupported. For instance, my Chromium browser cannot play `video/mp4`, but it can play `video/ogg`. So I would expect this to render the fallback text.

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Instead, I just get a video player with nothing in it because it can't load the mp4 file.

Is there a way to have a fallback in HTML 5 video when there is no usable video source? I am aware that the fallback I was attempting is only for old browsers, but I still need a fallback for no available source.

Comment: The fallback is only shown if the _HTML5 `<video>` element itself_ is not supported, not the video types in it.

Comment: @Xufox I realize that, but I still need a way to do fallbacks if it can't render any source.

Comment: How about using [`canPlayType`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7451727)?

Comment: If it can't load the source, that's a problem this element does not handle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, when you try to load unsupported media types in `<source>` element, an `error` event will fire.
You could then listen to these events, and if none of the sources is recognized, trigger the fallback :

```js
var sources = document.querySelectorAll('source');
var source_errors = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
  sources[i].addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    if (++source_errors >= sources.length)
      fallBack();
  });
}

function fallBack() {
  document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('video'));
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('No video with supported media and MIME type found'));
}
```

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="foo.bar" type="video/foo" />
  <source src="bar.foo" type="video/bar" />
</video>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Firefox - it throws a console log, but no error.

Comment: @Sora2455 what do you mean? On FF right now and the snippet works perfectly, displaying the message *No video with supported media and MIME type found*

Comment: My apologies, I was attaching the event handler to the video tag, not the source tag. My bad.

Comment: However, when I run the above example in IE11 and Edge 18 it leaves the video tag in place. IE seems to fire the error event at the video tag, and Edge doesn't seem to fire it at all.

Comment: This save my day, working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned in [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) a way to fallback.

"listen to the error event on the last source element and trigger fallback behavior"

```
<div>
 <video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"
         onerror="parentNode.parentElement.innerText = 'Your browser does not support the video codec' ">
 </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no HTML behaviour for this, so we'll have to add our own behaviour with JavaScript.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
  }

  function setVideoFallback(lazyArea) {
    var lowData = false;
    if ("connection" in navigator) {
      lowData = navigator.connection.saveData === true ||
        navigator.connection.effectiveType === "slow-2g" ||
        navigator.connection.effectiveType === "2g";
    }
    //DocumentFragments don't support getElementsByTagName
    //oldIE doesn't support querySelectorAll
    var lazyVideos = lazyArea.querySelectorAll ?
      lazyArea.querySelectorAll("video") :
      lazyArea.getElementsByTagName("video");
    for (var i = lazyVideos.length; i--;) {
      var lazyVideo = lazyVideos[i];
      var cantPlay = true;
      if (lazyVideo.canPlayType) {
        //Loop through the various source elements, and check if
        //the browser thinks it can play them
        //This works better if we specify the codec along with
        //the MIME type
        var sources = lazyVideo.getElementsByTagName("source");
        for (var i2 = sources.length; i2--;) {
          if (lazyVideo.canPlayType(sources[i2].type)) {
            cantPlay = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      //If on a low-data connection, remove the autoplay attribute
      //(it's only polite)
      if (lowData) {
        lazyVideo.removeAttribute("autoplay");
        lazyVideo.setAttribute("controls", "");
      }
      //If you can't play any of the available formats, skip straight to fallback content
      if (cantPlay) {
        //Extract the fallback and replace the video with it
        var children = lazyVideo.childNodes;
        for (var i3 = children.length; i3--;) {
          var childNode = children[i3];
          if (childNode.tagName !== "TRACK" && childNode.tagName !== "SOURCE") {
            insertAfter(childNode, lazyVideo);
          }
        }
        lazyVideo.parentNode.removeChild(lazyVideo);
      }
    }
  }
  /**
   * Retrieve the elements from the 'lazy load' noscript tags and prepare them for display
   */
  function setUp() {
    //Get all the noscript tags on the page
    var lazyLoadAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("noscript");
    var supportsTemplates = typeof HTMLTemplateElement === "function";
    for (var i = lazyLoadAreas.length; i--;) {
      var noScriptTag = lazyLoadAreas[i];
      //only process the ones marked for lazy loading
      if (!noScriptTag.hasAttribute("data-lazy-load")) continue;
      // The contents of a noscript tag are treated as text to JavaScript
      var lazyAreaHtml = noScriptTag.textContent || noScriptTag.innerHTML;
      // So we stick them in the innerHTML of a new div tag to 'load' them
      var lazyArea;
      if (supportsTemplates) {
        //(if possible, templates are better as they won't start any network calls)
        var lazyTemplate = document.createElement("template");
        lazyTemplate.innerHTML = lazyAreaHtml;
        lazyArea = lazyTemplate.content;
      } else {
        lazyArea = document.createElement("div");
        lazyArea.innerHTML = lazyAreaHtml;
      }
      setVideoFallback(lazyArea);
      noScriptTag.parentNode.replaceChild(lazyArea, noScriptTag);
    }
  }
  //If the page has loaded already, run setup - if it hasn't, run as soon as it has.
  if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
    setUp();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setUp);
  }
})();
```

```html
<main>
  <figure>
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <noscript data-lazy-load>
   <video height="338" width="600" autoplay loop muted>
    <!--<source src="./Sample.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">-->
    <source src="http://dl3.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis">
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Backgammon_example.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/BfbUe877N4xsUhpcPc/giphy.gif?cid=790b76115cadcffa59306b73776453f3" height="360" width="480"/>
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
   </video>
  </noscript>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <figcaption>
      A bunny emerging from his den and stretching.
      <!--[if !IE]><!-->
      <noscript aria-hidden="true"><p>
        Note: Without JavaScript, the above animation might not play. In that case, the animation can be directly accessed
     <a href="./giphy.gif">here</a>.
      </p></noscript>
      <!--<![endif]-->
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</main>
```

Using the canPlayType function, we ask the browser if it thinks it can play any of the source types. If it doesn't, we pull out the fallback content.

We encase the video in noscript tags so that it won't start loading until we've run the script (unless scripting is disabled, which is the desired behaviour).

We also use IE conditional tags, because oldIE can't read the contents of noscript tags with script.

(Tested with Edge, Firefox, Chrome, and every compatibility mode IE has. The Webm shows in all browers bar IE, which shows the GIF in every compatibility mode.)

Answer (score 0):

@Jaw.sh There's two fallback options that are commonly in use.

1. [Fallback to Flash version of the video.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211854/html5-video-flash-fallback-advice)
2. [Fallback to a direct download of the video.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350089/what-combinations-of-video-formats-and-video-and-audio-codecs-can-be-played-in-m/29355990#29355990)

Today's browsers (Opera I'm not sure and not really concerned), are all capable of playing [MP4 H.264](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference). So you shouldn't worry too much about incompatibilities, unless most of your viewers live in China.

Comment: You should read the comment under the accepted answer of your first link : "keep in mind the Flash fallback will never be used in HTML5 browsers, even if they cannot read the videos natively" and in the second link : "with direct link fallback if browser doesn't support html5 (some mobile devices):". OP wants to know if no sources types are recognized, so it assumes the browser does support `videoElement`

Comment: Flash can be played in any non-mobile browser provided they have the ubiquitous Adobe plugin. Yes, mobile do not do direct downloads, agreed. So let me just reread the question...yeah, OP doesn't mention mobile. Let me get my reading glasses....Nope still don't see it mentioned in passing. Mobile is a whole different set of complexities and the OP is worried about fundamental things like fallback.

Comment: No I mean, if the browser does support the `<video>` element, then those fallbacks, be it a text or a flash or whatever you like, won't be parsed by the browser. So if you need to fallback because there is no supported media in the given sources, but the browser does support `<video>` element, these fallbacks won't work.

Comment: In that case JW Player is a no brainer, but other than Chromium (an unstable developer version), what browser doesn't render a video tag? IE 8 and below?

Comment: That's not related to the question but yes, IE<8, OperaMini, FF<3.5. That's indeed why this question is interesting, since the used way to fallback for unsupported html5 feature is now practically unnecessary, and thus libraries like JWPlayer. But the element lacks in a way for fallback if no MIME types are supported ([an interesting reading for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats))

Comment: Also, you should remember that H.264 is not a royalty free format and that's why Chromium won't support it.

Comment: Yeah, Mozilla towed the line against using H.264 for a while but caved in eventually. This to me is a Renaissance, I'm not burdened with this anymore. So I leave you to the esoteric aspect of media, sir. :)