# Is it possible to add alt attribute for the poster of the video?

Tags: html, video

Can I add an alt info for the image used as the poster in HTML5?

```
 <video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: If you want descriptive content for devices that can not play the video – then you should place it where it now reads “Your browser does not support the video tag” (which is just an analog of the good old idiotic “your browser does not support frames”, which hardly made any sense ever either.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because it is an image does not imply that it will behave like an `<img>` tag. In fact in this case it is not even a tag, and there would be no way to do that.

Nesting `<img>` inside `<video>` would not have the desired effect, since the browser will interpret it only if it doesn't know about `<video>` tag at all (i.e. an old browser), and this is not the demographic you are shooting for.

What are you attempting to do here?

If you are adding `alt` to achieve some sort of search engine optimisation, then you should only do so in the event that search engine will actually recognise it as legitimate text to index and identify with the image in question. In this case it may very well be a good idea to add an `<img>` inside your `<video>` as so:

```
<video poster='image.png'>
  <source .../>
  <img src='image.png' alt='Image showing a cute cat' />
  Unfortunately your browser is too old.
</video>
```

If, on the other hand, you are attempting to do this to enable screen-reader to understand what is displayed there; then you are in much more trouble, since they are usually smarter than most search engines, and will often read text under the cursor. The approach above will not work, since `<img>` will not be displayed at all. I don't know enough about screen readers to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same question for [Coverr.co](https://coverr.co/?ref=stackoverflow_accessibility)'s videos - although they are sound-less, we wanted a way to describe the videos for visually impaired users or users who are using old browsers (which do not support html 5 `<video>` tag).
A nice additional benefit for making videos accessible is that you're getting extra SEO boost, since google can't crawl videos, but can definitely crawl the additional accessible text we're adding to our HTML.

Bottom line/TLDR - although `alt` attributes have been around and are widely used for images, it seems there isn't an equivalent native attribute for videos. The reasoning for that is [here](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/can-we-use-an-alt-attribute-with-the-video-tag/300322), if you're interested, but I feel it's not strong enough to miss out on all the benefits of having a simple tag for people who wouldn't be able to watch the video at all otherwise.

### What we DO have?

1. **Transcript** - a description of "what is happening in the video". There is no native support for that, but there are some recommendation on how to integrate it into the html. One suggestion which seems simple and effective (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912785/690866)):

```js
function showTranscript() {
  var x = document.getElementById('transcript');
  // var toggle = document.getElementById('trans_toggle');
  if (x.style.display === "none" || !x.style.display) {
    x.style.display = "block";
    this.text = "hide transcript"
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    this.text = "see transcript"
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var toggle = document.getElementById('trans_toggle');
  toggle.onclick = function() {
    showTranscript();
  };
});
```

```css
#transcript {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="title">Title of my video</h2> (<a href="#transcript" onclick="showTranscript()" id="trans_toggle">see transcript</a>)
<video src="foo.ogv" aria-labelledby="title" aria-describedby="transcript">
    <track kind="captions" label="English captions" src="captions.vtt" srclang="en" default></track>
  </video>
<div id="transcript">
  <strong>Transcript of the video:</strong> Transcript here
</div>
```

another option is using the [aria attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968626/690866), and while valid and even recommended, this approach is not supported as much.

2. **Captions** - if I understand correctly, the right way to integrate it is by using the `<track>` [tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_track.asp). **What are captions?** as taken from the [Media accessibility checklist](https://www.boia.org/blog/checklist-for-creating-accessible-videos):

> Captions should not be confused with subtitles — they are similar, yet distinct from each other. While subtitles are a straightforward translation of the video’s dialogue, often times in a different language, captions not only have a text description of the spoken word but also include description of the background music or sound so as to provide the same level of information as one would get from hearing the audio.

3. **Subtitles** - straightforward translation of the video’s dialogue. We don't need it in Coverr since all of our stock videos are without sound, but this is of course a very effective way to allow hearing impaired users (and 85% of the users on FB which never unmute the videos as they scroll their feed) to "listen in" to your videos. Can be embedded in the video itself, or added as VTT file and shown by [supported players](https://www.digitala11y.com/accessible-jquery-html5-media-players/).
4. **[Fallback text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430280/html5-video-fallback-when-all-types-unsupported)** (not for accessibility, but will help users who are using old browsers).

Useful links:

- Thoughts/plans for adding [native `transcript` tag](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/HTML/wiki/Full_Transcript) to the HTML standard.
- [Adding captions and subtitles to HTML videos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video).
- [Captions on the web and FCC compliance](https://mux.com/blog/captions-on-the-web-and-fcc-compliance/) + [converting to VTT](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/text-tracks/raw-file/default/608toVTT/608toVTT.html).

I'm aware this is not your common, definitive SO answer, but the current state of video accessibility on the web needs all the support it can get.
Would love any comments or improvement suggestions, as this is for us, still, an **unsolved issue** natively which should evolve to a standard solution ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use title attribute.

```
<video title="Video of Poster" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/media/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```