# How the transcript of a video should be visible to accomplish WCAG 2.0?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, accessibility, wcag2.0

I'm building a website that has to achieve the AA Conformance to WCAG.

We are going to provide videos and to do it right there has to be a transcript of this video, my question is, in html were is the correct order to put this transcript before, after. there is a valid tag to comply this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys!
I did my research and the final answer was matching the correct aria attributes and some html5.

```
<figure>
            <div class="video">
                <video id="main_video" controls >
                    <source src="<?php echo $source_video?>" type="<?php echo $video_source['mime_type']?>">
                    <source src="<?php echo $source_video_2; ?>" type="video/webm">
                </video>
            </div>

            <details >
                <summary aria-controls="transcript_content" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" id="show-hide-transcript" > Transcript </summary>
                <div id="transcript_content" aria-live="off" aria-atomic="true" aria-relevant="all" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" role="article"  ><?php echo $video_transcript ?></div>
            </details>
        </figure>
```

Comment: What are the sources the answer is based on?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, the transcript should be placed before the video. There is no tag specifically for transcripts - you will need to mark up the speech and descriptions using paragraph tags and any other useful markup like headings, strong, emphasis, etc. I like to use a link just above the video to show/hide the transcript so it doesn't take up too much room on the page until the user decides they want to read it. This [list of accessible media player resources](http://www.iheni.com/accessible-media-player-resources/) should give you some good examples.

Comment: Thanks stringy! your link help me a lot!

Comment: The details and summary tags, though not intended for this purpose, are actually probably the best for this, because they allow you to create a windowshade transcription toggle without javascript.

Comment: As of 2019, there is a W3C draft of a [transcript extension for HTML](http://w3c.github.io/html-transcript/html-transcript-src.html), proposing a `<transcript>` HTML element.

Answer (score 2):

WCAG provides two techniques for [Success Criterion 1.2.2 - Captions (Prerecorded)](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/media-equiv-captions.html#media-equiv-captions-techniques-head)

- [G93: Providing open (always visible) captions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20160317/G93)
- [G87: Providing closed captions inside the video](http://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20160317/G87)

The best way to handle both situation is to use the HTML5 `<track>` tag to specify the captions.

If your video is a ["media alternative for text"](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/media-equiv-captions.html#multimedia-alt-textdef) you have to clearly label it as such. Problem is that "[Using aria-labelledby to provide a text alternative for non-text content](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA10.html)" lacks of browser support, but you still can use it. My opinion is that transcript should be linked by a `aria-describedby`. But still, for users not using a screenreader, you have to make it clear (and visible) the role of text. It's always annoying to start watching a video after reading a text and realizing that the text was its transcript.

I would say that the best is to use something like the following (using `track` for closed captions and/or a transcript clearly announced before the video and indicated as such after) :

```
  <h2 id="title">Title of my video</h2> (<a href="#transcript">see transcript</a>)
  <video src="foo.ogv" aria-labelledby="title" aria-describedby="transcript">
    <track kind="captions" label="English captions" src="captions.vtt" srclang="en" default></track>
  </video>
  <div id="transcript">
      <strong>Transcript of the video:</strong>
      Transcript here
  </div>
```

*Note: You should not use the body of the `object` ([H53 technique](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H53.html)) element as this is not supported by modern screen readers which can handle navigation with applets*