# Offer Audio file in different formats with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm using the following code to play a soundfile:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'somePath/filename.ogg';
audio.volume = 10;
audio.autoPlay = false;
audio.preLoad = true;
// ...
audio.play();
```

And it works well. However, some browsers may not support ogg format, so I want to add mp3 format as alternative, too. How can I do this with javascript though?

For reference, this is how it would look like in pure HTML5 when you offer multiple formats:

```
<audio volume="10" preload="auto">
  <source src="filename.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="filename.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

So, basically instead of setting an `audio.src` I will need to add `<source>` elements to the `Audio` object. How do I do that though? Is there anything like a `new Source()` thing in javascript that I need to use here that I can somehow add to `audio`?

Bonus question: If the browser supports none of the offered source formats, can I somehow execute some custom code, like printing a message to the user, saying that their browser sucks? :)

Comment: if the browser is old, as with the video tag, you can use "Your browser does not support the audio element." . Just add the line under the sources

Comment: `new Audio(src)` is really just `Object.assign(document.createElement('audio'), {src:src, autoplay:true});`. So no, there is no Source constructor but basic DOM methods will do.

Comment: Thank you, @Kaiido. I thought there was some more magic behind the `Audio` 'object'.

Comment: And for the detect when no source is supported, it's already covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430280/html5-video-fallback-when-all-types-unsupported/32430863#32430863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not exactly what you had in mind, however you could achieve this via the DOM API?

```
// Create audio instance with different source times by means of the DOM API
function createAudio(sourceData) {

  const audio = document.createElement('audio')
  // audio.preload = 'auto', Redundant as source children are dynamically created
  audio.volume = 10
  audio.style.display = 'none'

  // Iterate each sourceInfo of input sourceData array
  for(var sourceInfo of sourceData) {

    const source = document.createElement('source')
    source.src = sourceInfo.src
    source.type = sourceInfo.type

    // Append each source to audio instance
    audio.appendChild(source)
  }

  document.appendChild(audio)

  // Update, forgot this - thanks @Kaiido!
  audio.load()

  return audio
}

// Usage
createAudio([
  { src : 'filename.ogg', type : 'audio/ogg' },
  { src : 'filename.mp3', type : 'audio/mpeg' },
])
```

Comment: One little thing missing: you need to call MediaElement#load so that it tries to parse its inner sources.

Comment: Seeing that you do an explicit `audio.load()` call, does that mean preload doesn't work on audios with multiple sources?

Comment: @user2015253 not for the ones generated by scripts (or maybe of you do append it in the document?) But better call it yourself.

Comment: @user2015253 it's necessary to call `load()` explicitly, due to the `source` child elements being specified dynamically. So technically speaking, the `preload = auto` is redundant here

Comment: @Kaiido No, I do not append the audio to the document. It's more like a sound that I manually play with javascript when a specific button is clicked -- that's also why I'd want to have it preloaded by then. But I guess `load()` selects the optimal source for the browser while also starting to actually load the file from that source? Is there a good documentation that explains what exactly a javascript method does, e.g. how exactly `load()` decides which source to take and what other tasks it might perform? I only know w3schools, but the info there is very lackluster.

Comment: @user2015253 Even MDN, (which is way more reliable than W3School since maintained by a community **and**, despite its name, all vendors crew) doesn't have its own page for this method. You can find an excerpt at [this page though](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods). But the basic of what it does is it triggers the ["load algorithm"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#media-element-load-algorithm), which is basically the same as what you get with preload=auto. Note that this is this algo that does call the "resource selection algorithm".